# ADSL is slow. I disconnect and reconnect, fast again.

Tags: wireless-networking, internet-connection

I notice that my ADSL connection is getting slow after a while, and I need to restart the modem in order to get full speed again.

What could be the cause? Is my wireless hacked? So that somebody else is using it every while? Or what else?

thanks

Comment: log-in to your ADSL router and check for the connected DHCP clients. If you see any suspecting clients than the actual connected device at your place, then your wireless may have compromised. If not, better checking with your ISP. Also, try using public DNS rather than the DNS assigned by your ISP.

Answer (score 0):

> Is my wireless hacked?

If your Wifi security is not WPA2-AES, or if it is set to that and your password is not a strong password, it's a possibility.  I believe WPA2-TKIP is difficult to crack so you likely do not have anything to worry with that unless your password is weak.

If your DSL modem is old and it's built-in Wifi does not support WPA2, you should purchase another Wifi router that does, and only use it's access point features (disable DHCP and routing if possible on it, configure the Wifi, and connect it to one of the LAN ports on your DSL box - then disable Wifi on your DSL box)

---

DSL connections sometimes have very limited outgoing bandwidth compared to cable connections.  Your "upstream" may be as low as 256Mbit/sec, while your "downstream" may be something like 1.5Mbit/sec or 3.0Mbit/sec.  If your upstream ("upload" speed) is saturated, TCP ACKs may not be able to get through to your box and this can actually slow down or break downstream ("download") connections.

BitTorrent programs can easily do this.  Lowering the amount of bandwidth such programs uses will help.  If you have a very large number of browser tabs open with Javascript/AJAX constantly hitting servers for updates that may be a contributing factor.  Viruses/malware can also do this.

You may also look into flashing your DSL modem with Tomato - this is a bit involved and may not be supported by your router, but it has QoS features that could help make sure no single connection completely dominates your DSL connection.  It's possible to set up a Linux system to do this but it's very complex.

If your DSL modem is more than a couple years old, you should look into replacing it.  It could just be a hardware issue through age.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely problem is a combination of (forgive me) cheap router and temporary changes to the characteristics of the line [ for example caused by weather or other DSL subscribers usage or tweeks on the ISP side equipment ].

A DSL modem takes a number of (usually sequential) frequencies in a defined band - like transmitting and receiving lots of radio stations at one time - and combines this into a signal on the other side.   Depending on your environment some of these frequencies are not available for use because of noise and the DSL line removes them.  The more that are removed, the slower your connection.

A good DSL modem will periodically retest (renegotiate) the frequencies available- Yours is probably dropping noisy ones but not renegotiating good ones until you restart.

The best thing may be to try another type of modem and see if that fixes the problem.  You might also want to call your ISP and talk to them - they may be able to change your ADSL profile at the exchange to make it less susceptible to noise and thus more reliable and/or get your line checked.

Answer (score 0):

I know a bit about modems, like the guy above said, if the modem is many years old, the capacitors can leak electrolyte and go out of spec and instead of just blocking the 'low notes' of a telephone conversation, it might also be filtering out some of the carriers used for data transmission so the modem blacklists them as noisy (quieter signal means relatively speaking, the noise becomes louder) which results in a slower connection.

It's probably not as likely that your Wi-Fi is hacked...usually pirates often steal/crack a Wi-Fi connection to download movies, MP3s, games and stuff without paying and you'd get a warning e-mail in your inbox from the man stating that there has been unauthorized use of copyrighted content. In other words--the line is BUGGED. If someone was running BitTorrent or P2P off your wireless, you'd know it.